# Render decals as 2nd pass?

Tags: render-passes

I have decals on my mesh in Cycles by way of placing it over my original material with a mix shader.

How can I render my decals alone on a 2nd render pass?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'd need either a separate object, separate geometry, or at least a separate material, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Can I have 2 materials applied to the same vertices/faces?

Comment: No and no. You can't apply materials to vertex, nor can you have more than one material assigned to a face. How would you render that?

Comment: I tried making a duplicate mesh that is transparent except for the decal, but then when I rotate the object, the decal always shows, even when it isn't facing the camera. Could you think of potential workaround?